# Why is rle in R returning incorrect lengths?

Tags: r

I am using the function 'rle' to calculate how many consecutive values there are in my vector. The first part of my vector is:

```
16992 32 96 8
48
144
8
8
8
8
8
8
8
8
8
8
8
```

but rle returns lengths of '1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 4 1 1'

and values '16992    32    96     8    48   144     8     8     8     8     8     8     8 '

There are clearly 11 consecutive 8s. Please can someone help? Thank you in advance.

Update:
I used dput() to view my data and it showed:

```
c(16992, 31.9999997615814, 96, 8, 48, 144, 8, 8, 8.00000023841858, 8, 7.99999976158142, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8.00000023841858, 7.99999976158142).
```

After seeing this, it looks like the values are sometimes just below or above 8, although this doesn't show when I View() the vector. Is this is the issue?

I am a bit confused as to why the values are not rounded to the nearest whole number. I applied the diff() function to these time points beforehand...

```
c(1390456832,
1390473824,
    1390473856,
    1390473952,
    1390473960,
    1390474008,
    1390474152,
1390474160,
1390474168,
1390474176,
    1390474184,
    1390474192,
    1390474200,
    1390474208,
    1390474216,
    1390474224,
    1390474232)
```

Comment: Please use `dput` to show the examplee as I can't reproduce it `v1 <- scan(text = '16992 32 96 8 48 144 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8', what = numeric(), quiet = TRUE);rle(v1)$lengths#
[1]  1  1  1  1  1  1 11`

Comment: It's hard to help debug code if we can't see it. What's the code that isn't working?

Comment: If `x <- c(16992, 32, 96, 8, 48, 144, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8)` then the result I get frtom `rle(x)` shows 11 consecutive 8's when I run it.  Please provide code that we can copy and paste without making any changes whatsoever.

Comment: The `8.000000023841858` and `8` are not equal.  If you want to make it equal, do `rle(round(v1)$lengths)`

Comment: Thank you @akryn. Yes, I realised it was because the data points were not rounded to the nearest whole number, after using dput(). It is working now but I don't understand why they were not whole numbers? (please see above).

Comment: May be those initial numbers were not whole numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The values were `float`s and they are not equal.  Check [Why are these numbers not equal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508518/why-are-these-numbers-not-equal) .  One option is to `round` and apply the `rle`

```
rle(round(v1))$lengths
#[1]  1  1  1  1  1  1 11
```

#### data

```
v1 <- c(16992, 31.9999997615814, 96, 8, 48, 144, 8, 8, 
   8.00000023841858, 8, 7.99999976158142, 8, 8, 8, 8, 
    8.00000023841858, 7.99999976158142)
```

Comment: I didn't know R used this system- thank you so much @akrun!